# Removing Referential Integrity on Stable Application

Tags: sql, database

I have read through some somewhat related questions, but did not find the specifics related to my question.

If I have a stable application that is not going to be changed and it has been thoroughly tested and used in the wild... one might consider removing referential integrity / foreign key constraints in the database schema, with the aim to improve performance.

Without discussing the cons of doing this, does anyone know how much of a performance benefit one might experience? Has anyone done this and experienced noticeable performance benefits?

Comment: What if the foreign keys are marked as `ON DELETE CASCADE`? Now they perform a critical function. Why would you want to remove critical functionality to improve performance?

Comment: Even with out delete cascade, parts of the application might depend on certain inserts/updates/deletes failing on the database layer.

Comment: If the data is valuable your application won't be the only one accessing the database and it won't be the last. You also need to consider manual acces to the DB (e.g. upgrade scripts, import scripts, ...). Removing the FKs will give you trouble in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience with Oracle:

Foreign Keys provide information to the optimizer ("you're going to find exactly one match on this join"), so removing those might result in (not so) funny things happening to your execution plans.

Foreign Keys do perform checks, which costs performance. I have seen those to use up a big chunk of execution time on batch processing (hours on jobs running for large chunks of a day), causing us to use deferred constraints.

Since dropping foreign keys changes the semantic (think cascade, think the application relying on not being able to remove a master entry which gets referenced by something else, at least in the situation of concurrent access) I would only consider such a step when foreign keys are proven to dominate the performance in this application.

Comment: Apologies it took me some time to come back and choose an answer.

Valid points in many answers but this answer appealed to me the most.

When the current project I am working on is 'complete' I will try and gather some metrics about the impact of removing foreign key constraints.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that ON DELETE NO ACTION performs better than ON DELETE RESTRICT, specially with batch operations?

Answer (score 3):

The benefits (however small) with be insignificant to the cons.

If performance is a problem check the indexes. Throw more hardware its way. There are a host of techniques to improve performance.

I know you said not to mention the cons - but you should consider them. The data is a very valuable asset and ensuring its validity keeps your business going. If the data becomes invalid you have a huge problem to fix it.

Comment: With SQL Server, at least, there's a notion of trusted constraints. Occasionally SQL Server can elide joins if it recognises them as redundant (e.g. it's a many-to-one relationship and you're not using any data from that table, if the foreign key that enforces the many-to-one relationship is trusted SQL Server won't bother doing the join: it knows it's going to match exactly one row each time).

Comment: @TaSpeotIs - I have always believed that if you are using a database then construct the tables/constraints/indexes/referential integrity to ensure that the data that is held is consistent. Of course the database is free to perform any optimisations as it sees fit (and the people that built these databases have more experience/time to figure this out). Better let the database do it then trying to second guess a whole company of developers. I go even further any just only access a database ia stored procedures. This ensures that you keep business logic close to the data.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to decide between performance and validity is like choosing which arm you'd rather live without.  As others have pointed out, there's better ways to address performance concerns (like index optimization, hardware, query tuning).  In any well-designed database system, the performance impacts of reduced referential integrity should be minimal.

Answer (score 1):

It will vary from application to application. So "how much" will be a relative term.
Performance benefit will come while inserting or deleting records.

So if you have big insertion or deletion  operations which are taking time then it might help but i will not suggest you to drop it even if your application is stable because in future development this might lead to big issues.

Answer (score 1):

> one might consider removing referential integrity / foreign key constraints in the database schema, with the aim to improve performance ... [does] anyone know how much of a performance benefit one might experience

You've given us no information about your database schema or how it's used, so I'll be conservative and estimate your performance benefit could be between between ±∞% (give or take).

Removing foreign keys can improve performance from the point of view that they don't have to be checked.

Removing foreign keys can reduce performance from the point of view that the query plan generation can't trust them and can't take the same shortcuts it would if they were trusted. See [Can you trust your constraints?](https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2007/03/can-you-trust-your-constraints/) for a SQL Server example.

Foreign keys have more than just performance implications (e.g. `ON DELETE CASCADE`). So trying to remove them to improve performance without considering exactly what functionality you are removing is naïve at best.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really a fair question in the context of "only speak to the performance gains and not the drawbacks" of this decision (or likely most / all decisions).  Since you can't have the pros without the cons you need to know the full extent of both in order to make a truly informed decision.  And for this particular question, since there is at best only one benefit (I say "at best" since the performance gain is not as guaranteed as most people would like to believe), then we have little to discuss if we can't talk about the drawbacks (but we can at least start out with the benefit :).

BENEFITS:

- Performance: removing Foreign Keys could get you a performance gain on DML statements (INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE), but any specifics as to how much is highly dependent on the size of the tables in question, indexes, usage patterns (how often are rows updated and are any of the FK fields updatable; how often are rows inserted and/or deleted), etc.  While some questions of best practice can be stated to "nearly always" have a performance gain, any effects on performance related to any change can only be determined through testing.  With regards to the typical performance gains related to removing FKs, that is something you are not likely to see until you get into relatively large numbers of rows (as in Millions or more) and bulk operations.

DRAWBACKS:

- Performance: most people would not expect to see that performance could be negatively impacted by removing FKs, but it could very well happen.  I am not sure how all RDBMS's work, but the Query Optimizer in Microsoft SQL Server uses the existence of FKs (that are both Enabled and Trusted) to short-cut certain operations between tables.  Not having properly defined FKs prohibits the Optimizer from having that added insight, sometimes resulting in slower queries.
- Data Integrity: the primary responsibility of the database is to ensure data integrity. Performance is secondary (even if a very close second).  You should never sacrifice the main goal for a lower-priority goal, especially since performance gains can be achieved via other methods, such as: indexes, more/faster CPU, more/faster RAM, etc. Once your data is bad, you might not be able to correct it.  With this in mind:

  - Don't ever trust that an application is "stable" or won't change.  Unless the software is obsolete and nobody has the source code to make a change, it more than likely will change.
  - Don't trust that you have found all of the bugs in the code yet, no matter how "thoroughly tested" you believe it is.  The app might appear stable now, but who is to say that a problem won't be discovered later.  If you have more than 10 lines of code in your app, it is doubtful that it is 100% bug free.
  - Even if the app code doesn't change, can you guarantee that no other app code will be written against the DB?  If this is software that leaves your control (i.e. is NOT SaaS), can you stop anyone who has installed it from writing their own custom code to add functionality that they want that was not provided in your app?  It happens.  And even in SaaS companies, other departments might try writing tools against the DB (such as Support who needs to do an operation to help customers).  Anyone considering removing FKs is likely to not have set up permissions / security to prevent such a thing.
- Ability to fix / update: The app might be "stable" now, but companies often change direction and decisions.  FKs give guidance as to the rules by which the data lives.  Even if no data integrity issues are happening now, if there comes a time when the app will have new features added (or bugs fixed), not having the FKs defined will make it more likely that bugs will be introduced due to lack of "documentation" that would have been provided by the FKs.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, though I have one disagreement: "the primary responsibility of the database is to ensure data integrity." isn't true for a lot of databases (NoSQL databases being a prime example), and would be better stated as "one of the choices made in the development of many SQL database engines is to emphasise data integrity", or something similar. Regardless, I don't think you should ever be a slave to your tools. If you want to use a hammer to open doors, that's your business, not the hammer's (or the key's). Maybe you're a burglar :)

Comment: True, but if you keep using a hammer to open doors, you probably won't get (or keep) many jobs as a locksmith (or security guard).  While there's always an exception to the best use of a tool, an exception will never be a best practice (by definition).

Comment: @iain, it is an issue of context. The question is "FKs already exist ; should they be removed?", hence the data and tool both support relationships and it is almost a guaranteed loss to remove the FKs. I agree that it's fine that NoSQL and simple options like Excel do not support FKs, but that's irrelevant to this particular question. Using FKs in an RDBMS is the most effective use of the tool to ensure quality data and hence a quality app, and is not being a slave to the tool. Reducing bugs also increases customer confidence AND reduces wasted time, all of which is just good business.

Answer (score 0):

Referential integrity constraints may [in some databases, not SQL Server] automatically create indexes on those FKs; delivering much better performance in queries on those terms.

These indexes often *help* query performance, giving potentially large boost to efficiency. They also provide additional information to the optimizer, enabling better query plans.

If performance were an issue, there are many other things (caching, prepared stmts, bulk inserts) I would look at before removing referential integrity. But, if you had large numbers of active indexes & were reaching serious limits on insert speed, it might be considered as a last option.

Comment: The _index_ it creates improves query performance.. And in some cases, having the constraint might help some query optimizers make cardinality estimates? Just a guess on that second one.

Comment: My point is you dont create Referential integrity constraints for indexes. Indexes can also be created separately. So i dont agree that they help performance. Its an additional check which will impact data insert.

Comment: *Referential integrity constraints automatically create indexes on those FKs* MySQL maybe, but SQL Server does not.

Comment: Well, you can disagree as much as you like, but I've __seen__ this improve performance. Creating the FK constraint creates an index -- in almost all databases -- and putting those FK constraints & indexes in, actually supports the database retrieving data efficiently via your designed relational structure.

Comment: @ta.speot.is SQL Server no? That's either interesting, as a feature, or bad, as in blisteringly inefficient. I am at least mildly interested in using _custom indexes_ which "cover" the FK but have other columns as well, to support the actual queries.

Comment: Why should it create them? It's not its job to outsmart your indexing efforts.

Comment: I would be careful when saying "indexes are automatically created". As mentioned by ta.speot.is, SQL Server does not automatically create indexes on FKs (just on PKs) but I know that PostgreSQL does. And as loki mentioned, indexes can be created manually so even if created automatically that in itself is not a reason to use FKs.

Comment: Thanks for the informative tips @srutzky and others. Databases I've worked with, mainly did create indexes.. So this detail is useful. My recommendation is still to look for performance elsewhere first :)

Comment: @ThomasW, you are welcome. And you and I (and several others here) completely agree about looking for performance elsewhere first :).